# How to get k similar products using Mahout?

Tags: mahout

I have one product, let's say a book. Now I want to retrieve k products, that are similar to this product. How can I do this with Mahout?

The products are stored in a MySQL database so I'd use the JDBCDataModel.
For computing the similarities I'd prefer the LogLikelihoodTest.

But which recommender should I choose? It seems that all recommenders are designed

Comment: designed... ? Finish the thought and I'm pretty sure I can answer.

Comment: Sorry, it was saying that "all recommenders are designed to be used with user data".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to guess at the question here. You have user-item data, where users are real people and items are books. You are using `LogLikelihoodSimilarity` as the basis for some recommender, either user-based or item-based.

You don't need a recommender if you just want most similar items. Just use `LogLikelihoodSimilarity`, which is an `ItemSimilarity`, to compute similarity with all other items and take the most similar ones. In fact look at the `TopItems` class which even does that logic for you.

Comment: Thanks, so I gonna stick with the TopItems class! Thanks! :)

Comment: NP and I forgot to mention an even easier option... use an `ItemBasedRecommender` and call `mostSimilarItems()` which does the above for you.

Comment: That's the recommender I'm looking for! Awesome! :)