# Can Myrrix be used for user-based collaborative filtering?

Tags: mahout, collaborative-filtering, myrrix

Can I use [Myrrix](http://myrrix.com) for user-to-user recommendations like I can with [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org)? If yes, please describe, or give a link to a way to do so.

I wanted to use Myrrix for its easy-to-use REST API and because it's very fast and lightweight. I need to recommend to totally new users (new users, but they have 100 item preferences each) - the `recommendToAnonymous` of Myrrix could've proved *very* handy, but I'm not sure if I can use it if it doesn't allow user-to-user recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by user-to-user recommendations -- recommendations based on user-user similarity? No that is not how it works; it is based on matrix factorization. But that's just an implementation detail.

I think the question is rather, does it support the operations you want? If you want to recommend to new users, yes it can do that after just 1 data point for a user. Add the user-item pref via `/preference`, then just call `/recommend`. Or you can add all 100, then recommend. Or you can use `/recommendToAnonymous`, yes.

If you mean computing most similar users -- yes and no. No there is no direct API method for this. You will have to run a second model where items and users are flipped, and then compute most similar items.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer from you Sean! Sorry for being unclear, my exact need is this: I have a list of user-item preferences. I want to recommend top-N users to a particular user.

If I were to use Mahout,I could do this using MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel and GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender. I think you hinted at something that'd help achieving exactly what I want with 'flipping' in a second model? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Got it, you mean flipping the user-time columns and using /similarity/{itemID1} ? Will that be good enough? Would you suggest that as a replacement for the Mahout method, given my simple requirements? I'm trying to avoid Mahout since Myrrix is so muc simpler to use.

Comment: You can recommend users to users, if your data is really user-user interaction data (like, whether we are connected, the number of messages we've exchanged). Then your "items" are also users. Your input is like "userID1,userID2" (actually you should send that, and "userID2,userID1"). There is no flipping; the data is symmetric anyway. You can recommend users to users, or you can compute most-similar users, which will end up being slightly different things.

Comment: But my data is kind of like an affiliation network, rows being literally user-item instead of user-user. I can't be sure if similar items (after flipping) will give me good user-recommendations, I guess I'll need to try it out. Thanks.

Comment: I flipped the columns and tried /similarity from Myrrix, and also tried Mahout's GenericItemBasedRecommender.mostSimilarItems() ; learnt it from your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787468/how-to-get-k-similar-products-using-mahout) . Both work well! Thanks again!

Comment: if it really works well, it should be no problem to add another REST function for it